# Zero inflated and right skewed dependent variable – is the Tweedie distribution a good solution?

Tags: distributions, multilevel-analysis, skewness, hierarchical-bayesian, zero-inflation

We are conducting a variance decomposition using a hierarchical linear random effects Bayesian model to investigate the variance in a DV that is affected by three nested layers.  Because the DV is right skewed and zero inflated we have used a Tweedie link function (e.g.). Is this a good approach given our setting?

Comment: The Tweedie does look like an appropriate distribution, since it can accommodate zero inflation.  A primary objective when choosing the link function is determining which link function results in the best goodness-of-fit.  If there were a lot of zeros in the output variable, I would explore what happens if you collapse (recode) into classes like zero and greater than zero, or running an analysis without the zeroes.  After all, if a large proportion of the data is based on a zero outcome, the information among all those zeroes is invariant (s.d. is undefined).

Comment: Thank you very much. Highly appreciated!